# Oracle exp function numeric overflow error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I'm trying to do something like this in Oracle:

```
   select exp(300) from dual
```

And I get numeric overflow error, how can I make exponential from 300 or bigger number, because I have no idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Quick and ugly solution: `(cast (exp(150) as BINARY_DOUBLE)) * (cast (exp(150) as BINARY_DOUBLE))`; if you have to work with such *big numbers* may be it's worth to work with *logarithms* instead of values?

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/exp.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Boneist said, Oracle NUMBER datatype has its scale from -84 to 127. The EXP function is defined to take in a NUMBER and return a NUMBER. So EXP function can't be directly used.

There are some workarounds though.

1. Binary_double can store 1.79E308. So for numbers upto E308, you can use that by breaking the exponents into NUMBERs smaller than E127, cast them into BINARY_DOUBLE and multiplying the result.
2. You could also use an [external function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_extern_proc.htm) in Java/C++/VB etc. to calculate the exponent and return the result as a string. This would assume that you don't have to do any computations on the result, or else you'd need to create an external function that returns the final result after all the necessary computations.

Comment: Thanks all, I will try the first step of ruudvan2002 answer.

Answer (score 6):

exp(300) is 1.942426e+130, which is [greater than the range of Oracle's `NUMBER` datatype](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i22289) - the biggest number you can have in Oracle is: 9.99...9 x 10<sup>125</sup> with up to 38 significant digits.

So in short, no, you won't be able to calculate exp(300) in Oracle.